# asp.net webapp bundleconfig switching from bootstrap 4.6 to 5.0 causing reference error

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-5

I have a webapp that I developed using asp.net c#. It's about 8 years old. I've been using BundleConfig and nuget manager since the beginning with no issues. Today though I tried using the nuget manager to upgrade bootstrap from 4.6 to 5.0 and received the error below. I reverted back to 4.6 and the error went away. Is this a known issue?

My BundleConfig containing the Bootstrap:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/utilitiesJs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-rwdImageMaps.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/js-cookie.js",
        "~/Scripts/popper.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js",
        "~/Scripts/common-2.7.js",
        "~/Scripts/commonBehavior-1.0.js",
        "~/Scripts/commonDates-2.2.js",
        "~/Scripts/commonDemographics-1.7.js",
        "~/Scripts/commonGrades-1.4.js",
        "~/Scripts/commonLocations-2.5.js",
        "~/Scripts/dropdown-2.0.js",
        "~/Scripts/analytics.js",
        "~/Scripts/dataTables/1.10.25/datatables.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/waitingFor-1.0.js",
        "~/Scripts/dataTables/datatables-overrides-1.1.js"
        ));
```

[image]

The full error message:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WebGrease
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteralProperty(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteral(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseVarDecl(JSToken inToken)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseVariableStatement()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunctionBody(Block body)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunction(FunctionType functionType, Context fncCtx)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpression(Boolean single, JSToken inToken)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionList(JSToken terminator)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseMemberExpression(AstNode expression, List`1 newContexts)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatements(Block block)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.InternalParse()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.Parse(DocumentContext sourceContext)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyJavaScript(String source, CodeSettings codeSettings)
   at System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
   at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths)
   at ASP.content_master.__RenderPlaceHolder2(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Dev\DMC\Content.Master:line 16

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    ASP.content_master.__RenderPlaceHolder2(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter, System.Web.UI.Control) in Content.Master
```

Comment: Hi, you should check this documentation - [Migrating to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/). As you can see, library has some dependencies changes, it may cause errors in your code. I suggest, to check libraries compatibility versions, probably, you should to update a few other libraries and it can solve the problem.  *Also, I want to note if your html code use different bootstrap styles from v4, you maybe problems in v5, because bootstrap changed different styles naming.*

Comment: imho the popper version is different and should be part of the bootstrap.bundle already.